# Subscriber left after increase in amount

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

A telephone company in a town has $ 500$ subscribers on its list and collects fixed charges of $Rs$ $300/-$ per subscriber per year.  The company proposes to increase the annual subscription and it is believed that for every increase of $Re$ $1/-$ one subscriber will discontinue the service. Find what increase will bring maximum profit?

My work

I assumed the amount increased per individual by $ y $

$ x $ be the subscriber left .

$$f(x)=(500-x)(300+y)$$

But I am not able to get relation in $x$ and $y$

Comment: Here $x=y$. The number of subscribers that leave are the same as the cost increase. See if that helps!